# Converting a map to set in STL

Tags: c++, stl

My goal is to use `set` instead of `map`. I have a `Product` class that contains the `map`

```
map<time_t, double> priceHistory;
```

and used in the function `output`

```
void Product::output() const
{
    cout << "Id: " << id << endl
        << "Price: $"
        << fixed << setprecision(2)
        << price;

    // Also output price history.
    cout << " (";
    cout << "History:";

    // USE ITERATOR TO TRAVERSE map.
    for (map<time_t, double>::const_reverse_iterator iter = priceHistory.rbegin();
            iter != priceHistory.rend(); iter++)
    {
        // ADD CODE TO DISPLAY PRICE AND TIME OF CHANGE.
        // PASS TIME TO HELPER FUNCTION displayTime.
        cout << " " << iter->first;
        displayTime(iter->second);
    }

    cout << ")" << endl;
}
```

So I change `map` to:

```
set<time_t> priceHistory;
```

and implement the set as

```
for (set<time_t>::const_reverse_iterator iter = priceHistory.rbegin();
            iter != priceHistory.rend(); iter++)
    {
        // ADD CODE TO DISPLAY PRICE AND TIME OF CHANGE.
        // PASS TIME TO HELPER FUNCTION displayTime.
        cout << " " << *iter;
        displayTime(*iter);
    }
```

but I am now getting an error in main where priceHistory is defined:

```
Error 1 error C2676: binary '[' : 'std::set<time_t,std::less<_Kty>,
std::allocator<_Kty>>' does not define this operator or a conversion 
to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

time_t currTime = time(NULL);
priceHistory[currTime] = newPrice;
```

I'm unsure of where my error(s) are in this case?

Comment: `std::map` stores {key, value} pairs. `std::set` only stores keys. By switching to `std::set`, you no longer have a spot in which to store `newPrice`. So either keep the map, or drop `newPrice`, as in `priceHistory.insert(currTime)` (of course, without prices, it wouldn't be much of a price history).

Comment: "My goal is to use set instead of map" is like saying "my goal is to use a hammer instead of a screwdriver" - they are different tools for different tasks, either you change even the task you are trying to solve, or you are going to fail hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::map` stores key-value pairs.

```
map<time_t, double> priceHistory;
```

this means you can store price at specified time.

`std::set` only stores keys.

```
set<time_t> priceHistory;
```

This implies you can only store time now.

You cannot do this:

```
priceHistory[currTime] = newPrice;
```

this will work:

```
priceHistory.insert(currTime);
```

If you still insist on using std::set, make a pair of {time,price} and maintain that in set.

```
set<pair<time_t,double> > priceHistory;
```

`std::set` would be a good choice if you want to perform some mathematical operations such as union,intersection etc.
These operations are available in header `<algorithm>`

But if you want something really quick for a key,value lookup, consider going for `unordered_map(hashtable)`